# GCC error in python virtual environment in docker

Tags: python, docker, gcc, pip, virtualenv

I have a docker file where i am creating a virtual environment in python 2.7.15 and installing all required python dependencies for my project.

Some of the dependencies require gcc to compile like pandas, lz4 .. are failing with below error,

> ```
>  pandas/io/sas/sas.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>      #include "Python.h"
>                         ^
>     compilation terminated.
>     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
> ```

Even i tired installing python-devel , gcc also in the docker. But doesn't help.

```
RUN yum install -y python-pip python-devel gcc
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM registry-access-redhat-com.repo.lab.pl.*-*.com/rhel7.5

# CONFIGURE YUM
RUN rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/*
ADD resources/yum.repos.d/* /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN echo "sslverify=false" >> /etc/yum.conf

# INSTALL REQUIRED SYSTEM PACKAGES 
RUN yum install -y python-pip python-devel gcc && yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
RUN yum install -y wget && yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum && wget http://repo.lab.pl.alcatel-lucent.com/eden-yum-releases/installation-packages-rpm/python-2.7.15-2.x86_64.rpm

RUN yum install -y python-2.7.15-2.x86_64.rpm && yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

#DOWNLAOD LATEST PIP
RUN wget -P /tmp/ https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

#INSTALL PIP ON PYTHON 2.7.15
RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install --find-links /tmp --upgrade --no-index /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

# CREATE foo GROUP AND USER
RUN groupadd foo
RUN useradd -d /home/foo -ms /bin/bash -g foo foo

# SETUP BASHRC for foo user
COPY file/.bashrc /home/foo
COPY file/.bash_profile /home/foo
RUN chown foo:foo /home/foo/.bash_profile
RUN chown foo:foo /home/foo/.bashrc

# SET WORKING DIRECTORY TO /home/foo
WORKDIR /home/foo

#CREATE VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT
RUN wget -P /tmp/ https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/16/da8cb8046149d50940c6110310983abb359bbb8cbc3539e6bef95c29428a/setuptools-40.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
RUN wget -P /tmp/ https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/17/9b7b6cddfd255388b58c61e25b091047f6814183e1d63741c8df8dcd65a2/virtualenv-16.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install --find-links /tmp --upgrade --no-index /tmp/virtualenv-16.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install --find-links /tmp --upgrade --no-index /tmp/setuptools-40.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin/virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 enet
RUN chown -R foo:foo /home/foo/enet
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
RUN source /home/foo/enet/bin/activate
RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /home/foo/enet/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install --find-links /tmp --upgrade --no-index /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /home/foo/enet/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install scipy
RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /home/foo/enet/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install openpyxl
RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /home/foo/enet/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install confluent-kafka

RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /home/foo/enet/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install cython

RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /home/foo/enet/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install pandas

RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /home/foo/enet/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install lz4
```

How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile also?

Comment: Try installing specific devel package `yum install python27-devel`, just in case.

Comment: Why the need for a virtual environment in a Docker container?

Comment: I also recommend deleting the shell dotfiles; they've come up in several SO questions and will not work how you expect.  (`docker run ... myapp` does not launch a shell at all.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should:

1. Install the python development files (as suggest in comment).
2. Use a `-I` switch in `gcc` command line to point the correct path for python include files.

Comment: And install the developer package with headers before that as vivekyad4v suggests above.

Comment: @binarym I tried pip to include header files. but still doesnt work `RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/python2.7" --global-option="-L/usr/local/lib" pandas`. How to use gcc. I am not aware of this. Python.h files are present under `/usr/include/python2.7`

Comment: when i change the LD_LIBRARY PATH to `/usr/include/python2.7`. pandas module installed successfully but not it my virtualenv path. `RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /home/foo/enet/bin/python2.7 /tmp/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install pandas`. It is installing `/usr/lib64`

Comment: I guess the problem is you specify `-I/usr/include/python2.7` but your python installation looks under `/usr/local`... And note that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is to specify path for dynamic libraries, not include file ;-) You must set up **both** LD_LIBRARY_PATH and `-I` correctly.